# Content of element doesn't refresh after onBlur action

Tags: jquery, html, refresh, reload, onblur

I try to edit content of an select input when text entered to a textbox by using jQuery.
This is my TextBox

`<input id="id_subsector_selector" type="text" maxlength="100" name="subsector_selector" onblur="onSubSectorSelectorChange(this);"/>`

and this is my multiple selectbox

`<select id="id_subsector" name="subsector" multiple="multiple">
<option value="14">Yazılımevi </option>
</select>`

This is my javascript function(I know this is trivial)

```
function onSubSectorSelectorChange(item) {
    $('select#id_subsector').html("");
}
```

The question is when I enter a character to the textbox, althought onSubSectorSelectorChange function is triggered, selectbox content doesn't change until I click on somewhere on page or press tab button.

The problem may be the trigger action which is "onBlur" but I couldn't find a proper function. 
I am waiting for any comment or solution!

Thanks

Comment: What do you actually want it to do? Change the value of the select every time the user types a character? If so you want the keyup event. If you're using jquery I would setup the events using that rather than attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

blur is triggered when the element loses focus. What you are after is the keyup event:

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: This is definetely what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want execute the method `onSubSectorSelectorChange` on keydown, you need use attribute `onkeydown` instead. The `onblur` will work only if you change focus.

Take a look about `onkeydown`, `onkeypress` and `onkeyup` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the onblur attribute althogether, and late-bind in `document.ready()` event to the `keyup` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_subsector").keyup(function(){
        onSubSectorSelectorChange(this);
    });
});
```

Or even more concisely:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_subsector").keyup(function(){
        $(this).html("");
    });
});
```